# How can I set the default project to install in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, project, libraries

I have an android app with some libraries that are projects too and appear in the list of the left in AS. When I run it in my device it's all ok, but in some others it installs the library as an app and shuts down because it calls the launcher activity but dont recognize the resources from my app, only from my lib.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Configuration page, there you can set a default application.

I wonder why your library project can be installed, is it an android library or a nornal android project?

[image: Run Configuration]

[image]

Comment: Maybe an android project, but in my other device it compiles the two projects together @wrkwrk

Comment: If it's just a library, consider making it an android library module, and add it as the main app's module dependency. library module's output file is ***.aar and will not be installed to your phone. @JaumeColomFerrer